# Does factory default car cover (parachute material) provide UV protection to car?

Tags: car

I park my car outside and in sun. I cover my car with the dealer provided car cover which is made of parachute material. I would like to know if the parachute material car covers block UV rays. If so, to what extent they provide protection from UV rays?
This would help me understand to what extent it would provide protection to my car paint from fading.

Car - Hyundai Venue.

Car Cover - From car dealer, parachute material.

Comment: Welcome.  I don’t know the answer to this, but if you can see light through it, then UV will likely get through.  You haven’t given any information about the specific one you have either.  I however would be more concerned about leaving a covering on my car that would be slowly wearing the paint away when the cover moves in the wind.  See - https://www.skincancer.org/blog/dress-to-protect-5-things-that-affect-how-well-your-clothes-block-uv-rays/

Comment: do people actually worry about such things?!

Comment: @user253751 if you are car enthusiasts and love your car then you would.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the details of the material which you have. We don't have that material.
Once you check the detail for that sheet then you will know how the material behaves in UV and what protection it provides.

Most new cars now have sufficient UV protection anyway built into the paint system applied to the car. It is mostly older cars that suffer from UV degradation.

Comment: When you say most new cars now have sufficient UV protection, do you mean the car paint/ clear coat would have good UV protection? or the car cover you meant?

Comment: I tried to enquire about the material. However, I couldn't get a proper/clear answer from them on the material. All that I know is it is parachute material.